# How to set up environment variables in Digital Ocean?

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, digital-ocean

Earlier I used Heroku and setting environment variables was very easy.

```
heroku config:set my_variable="TEST"
```

Now , I have started using Digital Ocean and I can't figure out how to set it.My server is on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

use command on terminal

`export YOUR_VARIABLE=/your/location`

Documentation about this
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: In addition, use the above to set environment variables for droplets. For app platform, you can either upload a .env file or do as instructed in the following link link https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/use-environment-variables/